# PHP with bootstrap, delete subject

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem when I want to delete a subject from admin panel,
If I click in Delete button that show a modal that see Are you sure you want to DELETE?
the problem if I click YES the code delete Other subject :'(
this my code :'(

```html
<td><a href="#del" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs navbar-btn">Delete</a>
</td>

</tr>

<div class="modal fade" id="del" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p>Supprimer !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Vous voulez vraiment supprimer ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Non</a>
        <a href="projetslist.php?del_pro='.$rows['idprojets'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Oui</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
';
```

Code PHP

```html
if(isset($_GET['del_pro'])){
   $del = $_GET['del_pro'];
   $sql = "DELETE FROM projets WHERE idprojets = '$del' ";
   if($run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-success">Vous avez supprimer la pub avec success</div>';
   }
  }
```

That delete the Last subject

Comment: Can you add the php code as well? :) Would be helpful to try and find a solution

Comment: @VirginieLGB I Add it in the post

Comment: This html code is inside a foreach() that iterates the $rows variable? You have X modals (as many as number of rows?). Make sure that the apropiate modal is showing and not another (with firebug i.e, finding the `"projetslist.php?delpro='.$rows['idprojets'].'"` real value).

Comment: @JP.Aulet Can you correct me the code :'( because I'm beginner in the PHP language :'(

Comment: @VirginieLGB My Code delete the last subject

Comment: `$del = $_GET['del_pro'];
   $sql = "DELETE FROM projets WHERE idprojets = '$del' ";`  --> Where do you strip this input? Prone to SQLi injections. Or just consider using a more secure - less depreciated - interface to do your database queries like PDO (prepare statements)

Comment: The problem is the modal that not remind the ID

Comment: @JP.Aulet 
 
Do you have a gmail ? because I want to send the complete code the insert that, because I don't know how to insert this code :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this (I write it quick! could have some errors) and is not functional code, you must edit some parts:

```
<table>
<!-- iterate with php the $projects object (or whatever the name is) -->
<?php foreach($projects as $row){ ?>
  <tr><!-- your td of the project... -->
     <td><a id="<?php $rows['idprojets']; ?>" href="#del" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs navbar-btn">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="del" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p>Supprimer !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Vous voulez vraiment supprimer ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Non</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger delete_row">Oui</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bdn-danger').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get the id of the clicked 'a'
            $('.modal').modal(); //show the modal

            $('.delete_row').click(function(){
                var url = "projetslist.php?del_pro="+id; //pass the id throught get
                $.get(url, function(){ //doSomething; }); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then in the php part:

```
$_GET['del_pro']
```

Comment: Do you have a gmail ? because I want to send the complete code the insert that, because I don't know how to insert this code :'(

Comment: First you need to read more about how integrate PHP + HTML + js, because if not doing this way, you will have a code that you couldn't maintain. Read more i.e in this tutorial very similar at what you want: http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/delete-data-from-mysql-with-confirmation.html  and http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/08/delete-data-from-mysql-with-confirmation-message-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Snippets of your code are

```
<a href="projetslist.php?delpro='.$rows['idprojets'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Oui</a>
```

And

```
        if(isset($_GET['del_pro'])){
            $del = $_GET['del_pro'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM projets WHERE idprojets = '$del' ";
            if($run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-success">Vous avez supprimer la pub avec success</div>';
            }
        }
```

As you can see, you have 2 different variables: delpro and del_pro

You need to make these changes:

```
<a href="projetslist.php?del_pro='.$rows['idprojets'].'" class="btn btn-danger">Oui</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your GET is going to delpro but in your PHP script you are looking for del_pro